# How to check if a variable or function exists in std?(in c++)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using std in my code(`using namespace std`)(I know it's not so good & should be avoided) and then I wondered which names are available to be used for variables or functions and which are already occupied so I searched for the list of the std variables & functions but I didn't find it.

PS. my code is actually a homework so there is no expanding dream and also cause it's a homework **I'm expected to use std** ( :| )(and even if I'm not I'm just curious about the answer). so my problem is what are the vars & funcs that are existing in std **right now**.

Comment: The whole point of having the standard stuff in the std namespace is so that you don't have to worry about it. If you don't do dumb stuff like `use namespace std;` you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You are mistaken thinking you are expected to do this.

Comment: @SergeyA no no, I assure you it's not a mistake and even if it is I'm just curious about it.

Comment: Language clarification: Are you assuming you *have* to `using namespace std` in order to access members of `std`? You know about `std::` prefixes? Do you know about the `using std::namehere;` syntax, e.g. `using std::cout`? http://ideone.com/e3Axtt -- people here aren't telling you to stop your use of `std` they're telling you to stop writing `using namespace std`.

Comment: @kfsone yes, I knew it. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no definitive list of names inside `std` - it can always be expanded, and was created exactly for that purpose. Therefore, stop `using` the namespace once and for all.

In other words, C++ standard prescribes what names **have** to be there, but by no means it limits the overall names set to those prescribed. Implementations often put a lot of other helper functions or classess into this namespace.

Comment: my code is actually a homework so there is no expanding dream and also cause it's a homework I'm somewhat expected to use std ( :| ). so my problem is what are the vars & funcs that are existing in std right now.

Comment: Is it really true that implementations can put non-standard library names in `std` (other than those beginning with `_` or `__`?)

Comment: @Bat, no you are not expected to do this.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I think it is. I have never seen anything which would prohibit them from doing so. On the other hand, I am not a good language lawyer.

Comment: @SergeyA, can you briefly explain for me why should 'using namespace' be avoided?

Comment: @gen, there is a wonderful SO question which is the first link returned when you google exactly those words.

Answer (score 1):

As the others suggested, stop `using namespace std` - this is **bad** practice.

I'd also suggest that you stop `using` any namespace. This way your code reads better, you avoid shadowing things and name clashes and, most importantly, you are always in charge of your codebase: you know where the things you use come from and what their broader scope/purpose may be. This can make your code more maintainable: for example it's easier to see what headers are not in use. what kind of functions are just auxillary/internal etc.

This is primarily a matter of taste, but I'd further suggest that you use namespaces or verbose descriptive names yourself (at least for those objects that don't have very short scope). All contemporary IDE's offer autocompletion so you won't even have to type this more than once. In my code I use things such as:

```
bool has_the_loader_finished;
bool should_the_program_quit;
void helper::setup::setup_animation();
```

all the time. This way a. I don't really need many comments in my code, most of the things are self-explanatory so I reserve comments only for special things and b. I'm sure that there will be no name clashes and c. I don't have to spent time trying to debug/refactor code where I no longer remember what things such as

```
int i;
bool flag;
void setup();
```

stand for..

There are of course cases where `using` is intuitive, such as:

```
using std::placeholders
ExampleFunction f = std::bind(&Object::hello, &instance,_1); // instead of std::placeholders::_1

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto halfmin = 30s; //instead of std::chrono_literals::30s

using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds; // this is an alias basically
```

Good practice, however, is to always a. restrict using to those particular things you plan to use, e.g.: `using std::placeholders` rather than `using std` b. use aliases or typedefs and c. **limit the scope of `using` (and typedefs/aliases) as much as you can** e.g.:

```
int someFunction() {
  using namespace std;
  // no more than a 20-30 lines of code here
}
```

or

```
// someSmallFile.cpp
using namespace std; // this is valid in the body of this file only
```

Finally, **NEVER use `using namespace` in header files**. This will expose the internals of this namespace to all translation units that include that file and without your clients necessarily knowing about it...